# CakePHP Models - why isn't it for 1 item?

Tags: php, cakephp

I've been through the model documentation and can't find out how build models towards 1 item.... for instance, I want the current user model to have an `addOpenId($openIdHash)`, but how do I do that without having to pass the user id to the function?

I'm looking for something like...

```
$user = $this->SobForm->get($userId);
$user->addOpenId($openIdHash);
```

I'm saying, it seems like CakePHP is built around models that don't control a single element, so the controller could have a function that is "$user->getAllUsers()" whereas to me, that's not a model, that's a manager, or helper.  How can I use a model in CakePHP where it's singular, so it only effects 1 item, or only contains functions that are related to a single item instead of functions that effect all items.

Is there any support for this kind of functionality or do I have to built it all from scratch?

Comment: Could you explain it better? I didn't got too much...

Comment: Not really. Easy response: Create a model that affect only one item. It's you building your models. Create them as you need.

Comment: Do I have to build it all myself though?  Is data for a singular item stored in the model at any point or do I need to add support for that?

Comment: You should create a model that accessing the database, affects only one item of it. I don't think there are premade stuff for that.

Answer (score 0):

SobForm seems awfully familiar to me...  I think what you are trying to do is treat the variable of $user as a class, and it isn't.  The Model is a class, and so is the controller, but an individual variable that is the result of a database query can not be a class.  What you could do is something like `$user = $this->OpenIdHelper->add($user,$openIdHash)` and have it return the new array with the openId added, then i assume you will be doing a `$this->SobForm->save($user)` on it?  (P.S. are you working on the Summaries project?)  You can also add your own custom functions to save or update certain data in the Model or you can do a `$this->SobForm->saveField('fieldname','data');` to just save one field of data instead of everything again if you have the id set first.